# libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos8

I have provisioned a vanila centos and then executed the following commands:

```
conda create --name an-env python=3.9
conda activate an-env

conda install -c conda-forge sentence-transformers
```

I am trying to import a hugging face library:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import os
```

In a centos 8 machine I get the following error:

```
libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed it using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge sentence-transformers
```

Already tried the following:

```
yum install openssl.x86_64
yum install pyOpenSSL.x86_64
```

I also tried:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

and still get the following error:

```
libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: Does doing a `ldconfig` (or `sudo ldconfig`) and then trying whatever you're doing work? If not, please describe what you're doing that's generating this issue.

Comment: You need to have the same version of OpenSSL installed that your software was compiled against. Installing a precompiled binary built for a different version of OpenSSL than the one your distro provides is how you get this error. (Well, one way you get this error; another is to replace the OpenSSL your distro provides with one having a different ABI version, but that would break a lot more than just Python).

Comment: In general, this is more a system administration question than a software development one; it's caused by software being improperly packaged or installed, and the skills to diagnose it are something your friendly local sysadmin will have right at hand. (You might also think about using a package manager like [Nix](https://nixos.org/) wherein this class of problem is impossible).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy really appreciate your feedback. Unfortunately, I don't have a system administration in my place.

Comment: Do you have a source RPM for pyopenssl? Consider rebuilding it from source. (If it says its dependencies are unmet, there's probably a good reason for that, like it being generated for a different distro version than the one at hand).

Comment: ...anyhow -- part of building a [mre] for this would be describing the process used to get from a clean install of CentOS 8 to one that has this problem -- exactly which yum sources you added, if any; which RPMs you downloaded and from where; etc. Once we know how to produce the problem we can figure out how to avoid it. I'm still not 100% certain this is the most on-topic place to ask the question, but the same information would be needed for someone trying to write up an answer at [unix.se] as well, so the work won't be wasted either way.

Comment: ...if you're handy with Docker, using it to recreate the problem inside a container is one good way to build a testable reproducer that others can check their answers with.

Comment: I have updated the question. Really appreciate your pointers @CharlesDuffy.

Comment: I uninstalled using `conda uninstall sentence-transformers`. And then installed with `pip install -U sentence-transformers`. This solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the idea from @CharlesDuffy as he mentioned `You need to have the same version of OpenSSL installed that your software was compiled against`

I uninstalled the library using `conda uninstall sentence-transformers`. And then installed with `pip install -U sentence-transformers`.

This solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue when building my Docker environments. It appears that in `conda-forge`, some `tokenizers` builds for version 0.12.1 (more specifically those in `*_0`) don't include an OpenSSL dependency despite having been built against a specific version (apparently, >= 3.0). This can cause the conda (or, in my case, mamba) solver to choose this version despite it being incompatible with OpenSSL 1.1.1*.

To fix this issue while still using conda, I suggest to explicit `tokenizers>=0.13.1` either in `conda install` or `environment.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by finding & sym linking libssl.so.3 (from openssl install) into /usr/lib64

```
find / -name libssl.so.3
ln -s /usr/local/openssl/lib64/libssl.so.3  /usr/lib64/libssl.so.3
ln -s /usr/local/openssl/lib64/libcrypto.so.3  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.3
ldconfig
```

Note: There maybe other shared library files in /usr/local/openssl/lib64/ that may have to be symlinked into /usr/lib64/